# How I create a non-visible button in rails using a boolean condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, button-to

So. I'm in a loop

```
<% products.each do |product|%>

      btn_hide = "btn-hide-class"

      <%= button_to "expired",
                    method_path(@path),
                    method: "get",
                    class: "btn btn-expired-supply #{btn_hide}",
                    remote: true
      %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, in my CSS file I have

```
.btn-hide-class{
   display:none;
}
```

I don't want to do it

I want to do something like this, using a boolean condition for display this button:

```
<% products.each do |product|%>


      <%= button_to "expired",
                    method_path(@path),
                    method: "get",
                    **display: true**   
                    class: "btn btn-expired-supply",
                    remote: true
      %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: did you try adding style: "display: none;", to you button_to

Comment: You can use the disabled option. `button_to "expired", disabled: true`

Comment: @Joe I've tried it. But it didn't work

Comment: @Vimsha I dont want to disable it, I want to hide

Comment: have you tried using jQuery?

Comment: yes.. But i cant to do this in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets your products table has a boolean field named as 'expired' and its been mentioned in your Product model as attr_accessible.

```
<% products.each do |product|%>


      <%= button_to "expired",
                    method_path(@path),
                    method: "get",   
                    class: product.expired ? "btn-hide-class" : "btn your-class-for-this-button",
                    remote: true
      %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope, it will work for you :)